# Hyper-V VM uses 99%, but the host is only at 4%

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Our Hyper-V host has an Intel E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40 GHz (6 cores). The host owns a couple of VMs like DC, file server, print server and some small web servers. ALl of which are idling or not requiring much processor power. I lately installed a new VM that does quite a lot of computing. During those tasks the VM processor is under heavy load, with 90–99% CPU usage. But when looking on the host itself during that time, the CPU idles with 4%.

The vmwp.exe process uses 0% CPU power, so I suspect that the CPU usage of all VMs together are not added to the total of the host.

My question is just this: How can I validate that enough resources are allocated to the VM and that 99% CPU usage in the VM is really more than just 1% of the hosts CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

How many virtual cores did you assign per VM? How much RAM does your host have and what is the amount of RAM currently allocated to VMs?

Such issues mostly happen when you assign too many vCPUs/vCores to a VM. Start with the minimum amount (ex.: one vCPU/two vCores) and add more cores if necessary. Always avoid over-provisioning of CPU resources.

Speaking about RAM, always leave 2-3GBs of memory for your host. For example, if your host has 16GBs of RAM, do not assign more than 14GBs of RAM to your VMs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The VM has 1 core only. The host has enough RAM and RAM is barely used in overall. I don't have the feeling that you are answering my question.